# How to pass authentication to iframe from host app?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, jwt

I'm implementing a web app that will be used inside an iframe on a host app with a different origin. This host app will have a method to authenticate its users. I'm looking for a way to securely transfer this authentication details to my embedded app so I can make sure I display the relevant information to the correct user.

I've been researching for a while and saw methods mentioning CSRF tokens, usage of [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send auth details, etc. But I'm still not sure which method is the safest and correct way to handle this problem.

How should I pass auth to iframe from host app? Is it safe to add a auth token to url query params? Do I need to use CSRF tokens? Can I prevent users to impersonate other users?

Answer (score 0):

When you design app composition you must also account for browser security and deployment domains. Cross domain iframes showing secure data is no longer recommended.

**BUSINESS AREAS**

If the 2 apps are for different business areas, eg finance and marketing, then each app should get its own JWT with its own scopes and claims. Users then access data with least privilege. This is usually done via single sign-on.

**MICRO UIs**

If instead you have 2 apps for the same business area, aim to run the frame within the same web domain as the host. Many things are then easier and you will not need to cut any security corners. One option is to use paths:

- https://www.product.com/marketing1
- https://www.product.com/marketing2

If the browser needs to get API data from a third party domain, aim to do so via the app's own backend domain. A reverse proxy can enable this.

**SECURITY**

If using JWTs in the browser, you can write code to post them between domains, via the postMessage API. The JWT then provides access to 2 apps. If it somehow leaks in Javascript code, the attacker has access to both areas of data.

If instead you use secure cookies in the browser, recent same-site restrictions are likely to drop any cookies sent from third party iframes, so they don't work well either.

The best security solution is to use `HTTP-only SameSite=strict` cookies in both apps. If they are micro-UIs then you can use a same-domain iframe, and they will both have access to the same cookies.

If the apps have different privileges, then using an iframe is not recommended. Eg if you use OAuth and try to do a single sign-on, this is likely to drop cookies issued by the authorization server, preventing logins from working.